# What Conditions Make A Minecraft Hat Transparent

Tags: php, transparency, skin, minecraft

Basically I'm writing a PHP script that displays a Minecraft skin. I understand that the only part of a Minecraft skin that's able to be transparent is the Mask overlay area, or "Hat". The script works great until I reach a skin like Notch's (creator of Minecraft) who has an all black background besides the main body parts. I know that solid black (#000000) can't be a transparency key because I've seen instances where the skin has a black part on the mask, but still transparency. Also, when I open up my personal skin in Photoshop the background area is almost black - #101010 which is RGB(16, 16, 16), but still appears transparent in game. My question is how can I determine if a pixel is transparent for the hat? I may be over thinking this.

Here's Notch's Skin - [image]

Mine - [image]

Mine in Photoshop - [image]

Could I be wrong about the black transparency key?

Comment: I'm also having issues with this,

the skin thats causing problems for me : http://i.imgur.com/oSAnE.png

in game the white splodges dont appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image that contains transparency can have the transparent color set to anything. Most often when I create files like that, I actually make the transparent color garish, like a bright hot pink or something, so that it is obvious. However, the exact transparency itself is set in the file, not in php itself. Using a program like photoshop, you can go into the image options (example http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090430191631AA61iQJ )and set the exact RBG that you want for it.

If you are having trouble displaying the files as they are meant to be, I am going to assume that you are doing some on the fly manipulation on the image - which is likely causing the transparency information to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

pictures you uploaded are not transparent.

All pictures from Minecraft are PNG and PNG format has transparency. 
While editing the picture in photoshop you can see transparent parts as squares of gray and white. 
If I'm not mistaken transparency of those pictures set as index 255 in Color table. and can be any color.

look at following images:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Bqo0s.png]
[image]

they both have background transparency. but when you save them to your computer, background of one of them will look black and the other one as fuchsia (#FF00FF).

Transparency color can be set in photoshop when saving for web as `Matte color`

in PHP PNG library, you can read transparency color index (PNG8)